# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'locations.id' in 'on clause

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, dao

I'm trying to load activities from a database with a specific location. I try to do that with this query:

```
public function selectAllActivities(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `activities` INNER JOIN `locations` on `activities`.`location_id` = `locations.id`";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
```

However when I load the website, I get this error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'locations.id' in 'on clause
```

Comment: What columns are in the locations table?

Comment: @JayBlanchard id and name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a typo, but I can't explain it in comment because of the backticks.

This :

```
`locations.id`
```

Is meant to be

```
//        v-v------- Notice the backticks
`locations`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 `activities`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
```

Inner joins should read like

```
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

[You can read more at this URL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: it already says that INNER JOIN `locations` on `activities`.`location_id` = `locations.id`"